# How To rig this excavator?

Tags: rigging

can you guys pls tell how to rig the excavator arms?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: There are quite a few good YT videos on rigging robot arms including the pistons. Suggest you search for one online.

Comment: @ApasipepOyong: please click on "accept answer" so other users although know that the answer helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The rigging is fairly straightforward, except for the excavator bucket.

**1. The Main Bones**

Begin with the bones that move the arm of the excavator. Create the root bone, and place the bones along with the mesh. Uncheck the *Deform* option in the bone properties. It's a hard-surface model. Nothing to deform here. The mesh will be bound directly to the bone with the *Parent To > Bone* operation.

[image: main bones]

You can bind the mesh to the bones and they will move already. *UpperArm.002* is just a helper bone. You can probably get rid of it.

**2. Rigging the Hydraulic Cylinders**

This is not hard to do. You need two bones for both ends of the hydraulic cylinder. And one for the piston rod and one for the tube. Those move the mesh while the first two bones are the control bones. You need to bind the mesh to the bone in *Pose* mode.

[image: parent the mesh to the bone]

The mesh mover bones have a *Damped Track* bone constraint. To make them "look at each other". With a *Limit Distance* bone constraint you can limit the distance so that the cylinder doesn't break apart.

[image: hydraulic cylinder animation]

Add this hydraulic cylinder rig three times to the main rig and you will have something like the following. The red bones are the main controllers. The purple ones are a child of the respective main bones (*Base, Upper Arm, Lower Arm*).

[image: almost done]

**3. Finally, the Excavator Bucket**

To make the shovel rotate when the piston rod is extended we use an IK bone chain that follows the two mesh joint objects. The smaller red control bone *Bucket Joint 1* is the parent for the purple hydraulic head bone and the beginning of the chain. The yellow *Bucket* bone has the IK constraint. The IK target is a child of the *Lower Arm*.

[image: excavator bucket]

Happy digging!

[image: rig animation]

[image]

Comment: wow! a big thank you, man! you really such an inspiration.